# Jquery to slide left and right content off screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to get a slide left and right content that usually occurs in an APP rather than a webpage. Anyone can point me in the right direction with jquery ?

As you click on the Left (<) or right (>) button it triggers the white panel at the side to slide in new contents.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library to achieve what you want. A populair one would be [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).